# How to pass the url from json data to a div dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the json file which contains id and url of few videos. Now I should read the url from json file and pass it to a div src. By clicking the div itself the video should be load into another div.

below mentioned is my html where I read the json data and append to the "href"

```
<div class="div1" style="padding-left:inherit">
<div href="#">
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to pass the href from this div to src in the below,

```
<iframe id="videoplayerDiv" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="center" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and script for add src is that,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/video.json', function (data) {
        $('.div1').click(function (el) {
            $("#videoplayerDiv").attr("src", $(this).attr(url));
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you json is something like below.

```
var jsonData=[{id:1,"url":"www.youtube.com"},{id:2,"url":"www.youtube.com/1"}];
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON('/video.json', function (data) {
    if(data){
       data.forEach(function(i,o){
           var _div=$("<div/>",{id:o.id});
           _div.attr("url",o.url);
           _div.on('click',function(){
                $("#videoplayerDiv").attr("src", $(this).attr("url"));
           });
           $("#div1").append(_div)
       });
      }

   });
});
```

and your html

```
<div class="div1" id='div1' style="padding-left:inherit"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!. I tried this one but i'm getting the error "Undefined"

Comment: instead of src="www.youtube.com " its taking src="undefined" and I don't know why

Comment: print data, then print o.url check what it is printing

Comment: may b your array is coming in data.value